# JS Keep Dates with a difference of 1 minutes

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

Keep Dates with a difference of 1 minutes.

Given array

```
[
"2018-03-01T22:16:50.000Z",
"2018-05-07T09:54:21.000Z",
"2018-05-07T09:55:10.000Z",
"2018-05-07T09:56:09.000Z"
]
```

In this case, the result should be

```
[
"2018-05-07T09:54:21.000Z",
"2018-05-07T09:55:10.000Z",
"2018-05-07T09:56:09.000Z"
]
```

Comment: what about edge cases with three items? which items do you like to take if the values are inside of a 2 minute interval? please add what you have tried.

Comment: @STEEL only for my knowledge, what will be the result if you add this to your array: "2018-05-07T09:58:09.000Z"? I would guess 3 items, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is cheeking if there is a greater difference than 1 minute with the next date and adds it to an array, in the case of the last element is comparing with the previous.

```js
const dates = [
"2018-03-01T22:16:50.000Z",
"2018-05-07T09:54:21.000Z",
"2018-05-07T09:55:10.000Z",
"2018-05-07T09:56:09.000Z"
]

const result = dates.filter((date, i) => {

 if (i === dates.length -1) {
     var date = new Date(date)
     var prev = new Date(dates[i-1])
    
    if (((date.getTime() - prev.getTime()) / 1000 ) <= 1000) {
      return date
    }  
  } else {
    var date = new Date(date)
    var next = new Date(dates[i+1])

    if (((next.getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000 ) <= 1000) {
      return date
    }  
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks. The original code was actually Multi-Dimensional Array of objects. And hence I could not post my original code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This will work also with other values in your array

```
var arr = [
"2018-03-01T22:16:50.000Z",
"2018-05-07T09:54:21.000Z",
"2018-05-07T09:55:10.000Z",
"2018-05-07T09:57:10.000Z",
"2018-05-07T09:56:09.000Z",
"2018-05-07T10:10:10.000Z",
"2018-05-07T10:11:10.000Z",
"2018-05-07T09:58:10.000Z",
]

arr.sort();

var lastitem = null,
    retArr = [];

arr.forEach(function (item, index) {
    if(lastitem < item){
        var last = new Date(lastitem);
        var newitem = new Date(item);
        var diffMs = (newitem - last); // milliseconds between last & newitem
        var diffMins = Math.round(((diffMs % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000); // minutes
        if(diffMins === 1 && $.inArray(item, retArr) == -1){
          retArr.push(item);  
        } 
        if(diffMins === 1 && $.inArray(lastitem, retArr) == -1){
          retArr.push(lastitem);  
        } 
    }
  lastitem = item;  

});

console.log(retArr.sort());
```